# ABL Code If-Else statement not executing

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have the following code which should do a simple if-else statement using Progress ABL.

I cannot get the program to reach the ELSE statement even when the substring "*UK*" cannot be found. Can anyone see what I am missing:

```
FIND FIRST ttShipHead WHERE ttShipHead.ShipToCustCustID = "1404".
IF ttShipHead.AddrList Matches "*UK*" THEN
    assign ttShipHead.CheckBox01 = (false).
ELSE
    assign ttShipHead.CheckBox01 = (true).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you add some debugging:

```
FIND FIRST ttShipHead WHERE ttShipHead.ShipToCustCustID = "1404" no-error.

message available( ttShipHead ).
pause.

message ttShipHead.AddrList ( ttShipHead.AddrList Matches "*UK*" ).
pause.

IF ttShipHead.AddrList Matches "*UK*" THEN
        assign ttShipHead.CheckBox01 = (false).
    ELSE
        assign ttShipHead.CheckBox01 = (true).

message ttShipHead.Checkbox01.
pause.
```

This should make it clear what is going wrong.

Comment: I see this is marked "correct".  Does that mean that the debugging helped you figure out what was wrong?  If so... what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a whole lot about ABL. But I think the syntax is 
IF *expression* THEN DO: *work*. So try adding a DO: after your THEN

Answer (score 0):

If there's a message on the screen about record ttshiphead not found, then it's not running the IF statement at all.

Typically FINDs have a "NO-ERROR" followed by an "IF AVAILABLE ttshiphead THEN " where required.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Maybe some small changes to make sure you have record.

```
FIND FIRST ttShipHead WHERE ttShipHead.ShipToCustCustID = "1404" NO-ERROR.

IF AVAILABLE ttShipHead THEN 
    IF ttShipHead.AddrList MATCHES "*UK*":U THEN 
    assign ttShipHead.CheckBox01 = (false).
    ELSE
        assign ttShipHead.CheckBox01 = (true).
```

if you want to can add and else to show if record not available.

```
FIND FIRST ttShipHead WHERE ttShipHead.ShipToCustCustID = "1404" NO-ERROR.

IF AVAILABLE ttShipHead THEN 
    IF ttShipHead.AddrList MATCHES "*UK*":U THEN 
    assign ttShipHead.CheckBox01 = (false).
    ELSE
        assign ttShipHead.CheckBox01 = (true).
ELSE
    MESSAGE "NO RECORD FOUND".
```

Comment: only need a  DO: END block if you are doing more than one statement as part of an IF THEN or ELSE